# Does resolution or hz make biggest impact on battery life

Tags: resolution

I am planning on buying the new Asus G14 laptop. I am choosing between the 60hz 2440x1440 version or the 120hz 1920x1080 version. My question is, if the rest of the specs are the same, will the higher resoluttion or the higher monitor hz affect battery life the most?

Answer (score 1):

You can decrease both screen resolution and refresh rate while on battery. Though the *actual number* of physical pixels cannot be changed in an LCD, reducing resolution, in effect grouping pixels in blocks, should somewhat decrease GPU load, and setting lower refresh rate certainly decreases it. Also, viewing a comparatively static display rather than a rapidly changing video or a ray-traced game use less power.

A bigger factor might be screen brightness, though. Work in the shade, and your battery will last longer than if it has to compete with sunlight.

Other factors include wireless connectivity. Turn off Bluetooth, and use Ethernet rather than WiFi, where possible. If using WiFi, stay close to the router, because the transmitter in the laptop uses more power to compensate for a weaker connection.

So there is no clearcut choice between 60hz 2440x1440 version or the 120hz 1920x1080 in battery life; more depends on your usage -- games, pick higher refresh, image processing, higher rez.

Answer (score 0):

Not just the (maximum) CPU GHz (modern operating systems do step that down --if possible-- to conserve battery) and screen pixels (more the illumination behind the screen, and there it depends more on screen size than pixels --again, can be turned off/dimmed to save battery) consume energy (battery life). Need to count in disk, WiFi card, Bluetooth, ... Better check one of the myriard "compare PCs" sites, see if any compares the two you are interested in.

Besides, mi laptops are rarely far away from the nearest power outlet...